# Need help to Extract text in between <p class='otp'>23454</p>

Tags: c#, variables

Okay so on my temp-mail page, amazon has sent an email and in the source of the page from inspect element, there is this:

```
<p class='otp'>23454</p>
```

I have tried

```
String codess = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("otp")).Text;
```

but it says otp isn't a valid class/can't be found.
That `p` is the 4th p in the entire source code.
I would like to assign the value between, which in this case is 23454, to a variable which can be named anything preferably 'code'.
The number will change every time. Thank you!

Comment: I have tried multiple things! Like
` String codess = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("otp")).Text;`
but it says otp doesnt exist. I dont appreciate you coming here and saying i put in no effort, ive been on this for the past 8 hours.

Comment: Your question shows no effort before you edited.

Comment: There are just way too many possibilities for things to go wrong so a bit more context would be nice.

Comment: What type is that `driver` object? Are you using Selenium?

Comment: Yes im using Selenium. driver is the ChromeDriver. Regarding the answer below, what context would you need? Like mentioned, the code will always be `<p =class'otp'>somenumberhere</p>` and i just need that somenumberhere which will be different every time.

Comment: @NewCoder, my answer expects a string with some html containing that first string from your question. So you should either give it the whole html or some part of it, but that depends on Selenium, which I haven't used.

Comment: @NewCoder, any news?? Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are 100% sure the html will be like that and that there are no other `p` like that which should be skipped, you could use a regular expression like this:

```
<p class='otp'>(\d*)<\/p>
```

That will give you the contents, as long as they are just digits or empty. You will need to get the second group from the match (the first one is the whole match, including the surrounding html).

Example:

```
string html = "<p class='otp'>23454</p>";
var results = Regex.Match(html, "<p class='otp'>(\\d*)<\\/p>"); // Note you need to escape the \ from the regex
string value = null;
if (results.Success && results.Groups.Count == 2)
    value = results.Groups[1].Value; // This will assign 23454
```

If the html could be any different, with more attributes, you may need to use an html parser, like `HtmlDocument`.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the answer. I have a follow up question, the first line `string html = "<p class='otp'>23454</p>";` How will that work with other times when i do it? As the number will constantly change.

Comment: Well, of course that's just an example to show you how the regex works. You should use your input string instead. You were asked for context in your question but you did not provide it.